# How can I specify a different path to unzip for file unzip?

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to unzip a .zip file from source to destination.

It is taking the default source as:

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\Common7\IDE

The source is actually in my project.

#### Code:

```
FastZip fz = new FastZip();
fz.ExtractZip("Emp2.zip", Server.MapPath("~/Response Attachments/"), "");
```

Answer (score 0):

typically, we use command-line tool to do the individual job, you can run a script:

unzip XXX.zip -d C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\Common7\IDE